# Use polyhedron as graphics primitive, placing at point and scaling

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Can I ask an easy beginner's question, to which I'm unable to find an easy to understand answer in any of the texts I have (which are admittedly quite old, predating version 6 in some cases)? How do you use the polyhedra as if they were graphics primitives like Sphere and Cuboid? Ie, centred at a point and scaled. Here are silly examples to illustrate the point:

```
(* spheres along a path *)
data = Table[{Cos[t], Sin[t], Sin[t] Cos[2 t]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/24}];
Graphics3D[Sphere[#, 0.3] & /@ data]
```

[image: loop of spheres]

```
(* cubes along a path *)
Graphics3D[Cuboid[#, # + 0.1] & /@ data]
```

[image: loop of cubes]

So how to place icosahedra at specific points and scale, writing something like

```
Graphics3D[icosahedron[#, 0.1] & /@ data]
```

Edit: I think my problem is how to make `GraphicsComplex` and `Graphics3D` work together. Eg, where I currently have:

```
shapes[ct_, siz_] := {Sphere[ct - .2, siz ], Sphere[ct - 0.1, siz]};
Graphics3D[{{shapes[#, size] & /@ data}}]
```

I'd like to replace that `Sphere[]` with `icosahedron[]`. Am currently trying to make Heike's solution work...

Edit 2: Working fine now, thanks Heike. Not sure I'll get it 3D-printed though - looks a bit uncomfortable to wear...

[image: the platonic bracelet]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
icosahedron = PolyhedronData["Icosahedron"][[1]];
Graphics3D[Translate[Scale[icosahedron, .1], #] & /@ data]
```

[image: icosahedra]

Comment: Hi, Heike - thanks. I think I can see what your answer's doing (passing a GraphicsComplex to Graphics3D), so I might need to refactor my code, since I'm trying to call Graphics3D elsewhere...

Comment: @cormullion: `GraphicsComplex` is treated like any other `Graphics` or `Graphics3D` primitive so you could define `icosahedron[c_, s_]:=Translate[Scale[PolyhedronData["Icosahedron"][[1]], s], c]`.